# How to get event name for more than one alarm notification?

Tags: java, android, alarmmanager

I have set alarm for inserting calendar events. If more than one calendar event inserted, How to get event's name of event for which the alarm is ringing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you define the Intent into the PendingIntent for the Alarm you can set the Intent with defining different value to put into the intent as key/pair.

Same way you can also define the Same Intent for with different request code

here is the snippet code

```
Intent intent=new Intent(context,YourActivity.class);
intent.putExtra("your first value",title);
intent.putExtra("your second value", desc);

PendingIntent sender = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context,(int)requestcode, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);

AlarmManager am = (AlarmManager)context.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);

am.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP,alarm_time,sender);
```

As you use the intent define with the event value suppose title and desc now set into the PendingIntent with requestcode. this request code must be unique otherwise with the same intent and same request code will overwrite the existing alarm. And you have keep all the request code if in future you want to cancel the alarm at that time same intent and request code required for specific alarm cancellation